# boost c++ library object serialization problem

Tags: c++

The error was:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception
what(): input stream error
Aborted
```

I have these code in my main.c

```
Object *obj = new Object();
{
    std::ifstream ifs("FILEX");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> *obj;
}
```

"FILEX" may or may not exist before, is this the cause of the error? or it is
because I implemented the serialize method of Object class in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite reference page when using ifstream:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/

You're trying to open "FILEX" twice -- I assume that's not what you want to do.  I'm not familiar with boost::archive, but you can at least check if `ifs` is usable:

```
Object *obj = new Object();
{
    std::ifstream ifs("FILEX");
    if (ifs.good()) {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> *obj;
    } else {
        // throw an error or something
        assert(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: ... or you could just catch the exception that is already being generated. But +1 anyway.

Comment: @Martin: just a matter of taste. I prefer `if (ifs)` too, but somebody can think `.good()` part is more readable/informative

Comment: Also as a matter of taste, someone may want to do `if (ifs.bad()) throw exc;` and then do away with the else statement and indentation.  Generally, that's my preference.  But in this case, bad is NOT the opposite of good.  Just wanted to add that warning, in case anyone's unfamiliar with the quirks of ifstream.

Answer (score 0):

file should exist, only in this case you can deserialize something from it. as @Tim suggested, just check if file was opened successfully.

Comment: Is there a way to create the non-existing file as well as open the ifstream at the same time? of I should use if-else to do that?

Comment: you want to deserialize some object(s) from a file. first you need to serialize object(s) to this file. if file doesn't exist means you have nothing to deserialize. it's an error and you need to throw an exception (probably more informative than one you already have) or to workaround this case, e.g. by creating default object(s). in both cases you need that `if`